# Erase the memory cache of the PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I want to erase the memory register that stores the variables that are created while running python code (in QGIS).  I tried using `qgs.exitQgis()` based on [pyqgis manual](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html). But I get an error saying `NameError: name 'Qgs' is not defined`.

**Edit**: Realized that `qgs.exitQgis()` is not usable for my purpose since my aim is not to have a [stand alone](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-standalone-scripts) pycode that uses QGIS library, moreover I noticed that running the command `qgs = QgsApplication([], False)`, in order to define the variable `qgs` is making my QGIS2.14 interface unresponsive!

Apparently, I need to have some QGIS independent way to clear memory register.

Comment: It is a Python problem, see [Python: Memory Management](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/memory.html)

Comment: Did you define `qgs` correctly such as the way in the manual?

Comment: @Joseph , u sound to be right.. Let me check once..

Comment: @ Joseph , I realize that the method suggested in the manual is for [Python stand alone](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-standalone-scripts). But my purpose is not that. Moreover, I noticed that using the command ,  'qgs = QgsApplication([], False)'  , inorder to define 'qgis' is paralyzing my script and leaving my QGIS interface unresponsive!

Comment: As @gene mentioned, this sounds more like a python problem which is probably better asked in [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). Saying that, there are a few questions which pick up on this such as: [Clear variable in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237647/clear-variable-in-python); and [How can I explicitly free memory in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python). One of the suggested answers (which is what I do) is to create a function to set the various variables to `None`.